# d3.js line chart instead of area

Tags: d3.js

I have a working d3.js [area chart](http://jsfiddle.net/e9hmd/) How can I change it to become a line chart instead? I have been trying to include a line variable `var line = d3.svg.line()` without success.

Comment: There are lots of examples for line charts, e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add the following css, to show the area as line:

```
.area{
   fill:none;
   stroke:#000;
}
```

Live example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/e9hmd/3/

Here's an example using d3.svg.line instead of d3.svg.area:
http://jsfiddle.net/e9hmd/4/